# Measure of a set

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset R$ such that for all open interval I, $m^* (A \cap I) < 1/2 L(I)$, where L is the length of a interval and $m^*$ is measure, prove that $m^*(A)=0$.
I appreciate any hint to solve this problem.

Comment: Is $m^*$ the outer measure?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of countably many intervals. Now use the fact that $m^{\ast}(A)$ is the infimum of measures of all open sets that contain $A$

Comment: here is my solution. Suppose A = $\cup I_i$, $i \in N$, by assumption $m^*(A \cap I_i ) = m^*(I_i) < 1/2 L(I_i)$, so m^*(I_i) = 0. $m*A = \sum m^*(I_i) = 0$. But I think I do some mistakes. Please correct me if there is any. Thanks

Comment: A is arbitrary in that case that is not true.